# How find the minimum number?

Tags: python

I have this task I need to complete:

> "There are N athletes competing in a hammer throw. Each of them made M
> throws. The athlete with the highest best throw wins. If there are
> several of them, then the one with the best sum of results for all
> attempts wins. If there are several of them, the athlete with the
> minimum number is considered the winner. Determine the number of the winner of the competition."

I can find highest best throw wins, but I can't find the athlete with the minimum number.

**Sample Input:**

```
4 3
4 2 7
1 2 7
1 3 5
4 1 6
```

**Sample Output:**

```
1
```

**My code so far:**

```
row,columns = map(int,input().split())
matrix = [[int(i) for i in input().split()] for j in range(row)]
numbers = []
suma = []
for i in range(row):
    numbers.append(matrix[i][0])
    sumaa = sum(matrix[i]) - matrix[i][0]
    suma.append(sumaa)
new_matrix = [numbers,suma]
print(new_matrix.index(max(new_matrix)))
```

Comment: `min()` won't work? What if you define a variable `lowest_num`, then loop through all numbers and if it is lower than `lowest_num`, replace it?

Comment: it look like some online coding competition problem, if it is from live event is request all to restrain from giving direct solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = """4 3
4 2 7
1 2 7
1 3 5
4 1 6
"""

def winner(input):
    athletes = input.split("\n")
    best_throw = max(" ".join(athletes).split(" "))
    best_total = max(map(lambda s: sum(list(map(lambda n: int(n) if n != '' else 0, s.split(" ")))), athletes))
    
    best_athletes_indexes = []
    for i, athlete in enumerate(athletes):
        if best_throw in athlete.split(" ") and sum(map(int, athlete.split(" "))) == best_total:
         best_athletes_indexes.append(i)
    
    
    best_athletes_attempts = list(map(lambda i: len(athletes[i].split(" ")), best_athletes_indexes))
    
    return best_athletes_indexes[best_athletes_attempts.index(min(best_athletes_attempts))]
    

print(winner(input))
```

please please please do not ask me to explain this this is the first python i hav written in 2 years. i come from a world of type safety wth

my search history is literally "remove item from list python" the python standard library is strange

Answer (score 0):

It's answer

```
a = []
b = []
row, columns = map(int, input().split())
for i in range(row):
  a.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
for i in range(row):
  b.append([max(a[i]), sum(a[i])])

print(b.index(max(b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
row, columns = map(int, input().split())
matrix = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(row)]
matrix_max_sum_elms = [[max(row), sum(row)] for row in matrix]
best_athlete_ind = matrix_max_sum_elms.index(max(matrix_max_sum_elms)) + 1
print(best_athlete_ind)
```

***Explanation:***

First, we create a list of lists with an input value,
then we create a new list of lists, in which each list contains the maximum value and the sum of the elements of the input values. As a result, we take the index of the list that contains the maximum value and add 1, since indexing starts from 0